# EasyTimer.js + VueJS y addEventListener

Tags: vue.js

estoy tratando de implementar un contador con la Librería EasyTimer.js con VueJS, y no he logrado hacer funcionar, me parece es tema de addEventListener, la verdad no sé cómo funciona en VueJS y ni he encontrado información precisa para este tipo de situación, tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
LoadReports () {
  var aArea = this.$route.params.area

  this.reportes = []
  this.piezasCount = []

  Reportes.getCorrReportes(aArea).then(results => {
    if (results.data.status === 'ok') {
      var aIndex = 0
      for (var item of results.data.reportes) {
        if (!item.piezasDisp && Object.keys(item.piezas).length > 0) {
          this.piezasCount.push({ key: aIndex, seconds: item.piezas.fecha })
        }
        this.reportes.push(item)

        aIndex++
      }
    }
  })
},
TimeTracking (aSeconds, index) {
  var timer = new Timer()
  timer.start({ precision: 'seconds', startValues: { seconds: aSeconds } })
  timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    this.reportes[index].PiezaReqTime = timer.getTimeValues().toString()
  })
}
```

y en la plantilla tengo lo siguiente:

```
<tr class="text-white" v-if="Object.keys(item.piezas).length > 0">
            <td style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid #027be3;">{{ item.piezas.pieza }}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 70px; border: 1px solid #027be3;">{{ item.piezas.tiempo }}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 70px; border: 1px solid #027be3;"><span>{{ item.PiezaReqTime }}</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="text-white" v-else>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid #027be3;">--</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 70px; border: 1px solid #027be3;">--</td>
          </tr>
```

donde {{ item.PiezaReqTime }} debería el tiempo que va transcurriendo, pero no muestra nada, estoy seguro algo me falta.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Saludos

**UPDATE:**

Ahora creé un componente para mostrar el tiempo:

```
<template>
  <span>{{ timer }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import { Timer } from 'easytimer.js'

export default {
  props: {
    seconds: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      timer: ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.InitTimer()
  },
  methods: {
    InitTimer () {
      var aTimer = new Timer()
      aTimer.start({ precision: 'seconds', startValues: { seconds: this.seconds } })
      aTimer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
        this.timer = aTimer.getTimeValues().toString()
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Aún sigue sin mostrar nada

Comment: Apuesto todo lo que quieras a que this.timer no es el this que vos pensas. en JS hay un problema con los this.. proba agregar lo siguiente en tu ultimo componente: const me = this; (al inicio del init) y luego dentro de la funcion de addEventListener hace me.timer = aTimer.....etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que `this.timer` esta fuera del contexto de tu componente cuando lo usuas dentro del `callback` del evento `secondsUpdated`. Existen varias soluciones para mantener el contexto y detallo algunas.

Usando un `arrow function`.

```
InitTimer () {
  var aTimer = new Timer()
  aTimer.start({ precision: 'seconds', startValues: { seconds: this.seconds } })
  aTimer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', (e) => {
    this.timer = aTimer.getTimeValues().toString()
  })
}
```

De esta manera el contexto del `this` se mantiene y puedes llamar a la propiedad `timer`.

Guardar `this` en otra variable.

```
InitTimer () {
  var aTimer = new Timer()
  aTimer.start({ precision: 'seconds', startValues: { seconds: this.seconds } })    
  const _this = this
  aTimer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    _this.timer = aTimer.getTimeValues().toString()
  })
}
```

De esta manera puedes acceder a `_this.timer`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Aníbal con el arrow function ya funciona correctamente!